# How do I fix google meet screen sharing being very dark on Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ubuntu-22.04, google-meet

Issue: When I go to share my screen/tab/window on google meet, it comes up very dark.
[very dark screenshot of shared screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrEJg.png).

Any ideas how to fix this?

Actions taken: all of the following with multiple logins/out/restarts but to no avail

1. You might need to update GDM3 custom configuration file

/etc/gdm3/custom.conf

Uncommenting this will force the login screen to use Xorg. #WaylandEnable=false

$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE x11

2. Install xcompmgr using your Linux distro's package manager. sudo apt install xcompmgr After installing, open the terminal and run this command: xcompmgr -c -l0 -t0 -r0 -o.00 Open compton.conf gedit ~/.config/compton.conf Edit the following line: shadow-exclude = [ "name = 'cpt_frame_window' " ];
3. added google-chrome-stable --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland & to ~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop

set chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer

4. sudo mkdir -p /etc/pipewire/media-session.d/ sudo cp /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/media-session.conf /etc/pipewire/media-session.d/ sudo sed -i 's/#metadata/metadata/g' /etc/pipewire/media-session.d/media-session.conf

Yours at a complete loss after many hours of digging around :)

OS: Ubuntu: 22.04.1 - clean minimal install
Browsers used: latest Firefox and Chrome

Comment: I think that this question is off-topic here. I suggest you to ask in [meta.se] for a site recommendation.